# How to force combobox in listview to update when listview collection changes in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, combobox, winui-3

I believe this is a quirk of how the `ListView` works. I have included a problem description what I think is going on, and my question: how do I get around it?

**Problem Description**

I have a `ListView`, with a `ComboBox` specified inside of the `ItemTemplate`. The `ComboBox` shows an editable property on the items displayed in the `ListView`.

Per the "tip" in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/combo-box) (under the heading "Item Selection"), I am handling the `Loaded` event to initialize the `SelectedItem` property in the `ComboBox`. (I am doing this because the data is being pulled from an asynchronous source and may not be available right away - I could not get data-binding in XAML alone to work).

When the page first loads, this works flawlessly. When I try to add items to the collection afterwards, however - I get some unexpected behavior... despite using the same function (`SetItems()` in the sample below) to do the updates both times. Using the print statement in the sample below, I have confirmed that when the page first loads, the output is as expected: each item in the list has an output line, and the `SelectedValue` in each `ComboBox` (which displays the `Status` property on each item in the example below) is correct.

When I update the list later (after the page and `ListView` initially load), however, by calling that same `SetItem()` function (perhaps after adding an item to the list), the output from that same print statement is NOT as expected. Only a single print statement appears, and prints a seemingly random item from the list, along with the incorrect `Status`. This is unexpected because I am clearing the `ObservableCollection`, and re-adding ALL items to it (including the new items).

In the page XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyDataType">
            <!-- Some things omitted for brevity -->
            <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
                      Tag="{x:Bind ID}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Status"
                      Loaded="MyComboBox_Loaded"></ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The code behind with collection, event handler, and collection-altering code:

```
// The collection.
public ObservableCollection<MyDataType> MyCollection { get; set; }

// The ComboBox Loaded event handler.
private void MyComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the ID of the item this CombBox is for.
    ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    string id = comboBox.Tag as string;

    // Get a reference to the item in the collection.
    MyDataType item = this.MyCollection.Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

    // Initialize the ComboBox based on the item's property.
    comboBox.SelectedValue = item.Status;

    // Wire up the Selection Changed event (doing this after initialization prevents the handler from running on initialization).
    comboBox.SelectionChanged += this.MyComboBox_SelectionChanged;

    // Print statement for debugging.
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ComboBox for item " + item.ID + " loaded and set to " + item.Status);
}

// The function used to update the observable collection (and thus bound listview).
public void SetItems(List<MyDataType> items)
{
    // Clear the collection and add the given items.
    this.MyCollection.Clear();
    items.ForEach(i => this.MyCollection.Add(i));
}
```

**What I think is going on**

I believe this is a quirk of how the `ListView` works. I remember reading somewhere from past experience with item repeaters in a different part of .NET that the UI for each item may not actually be created new each time; UI items may be recycled and reused for efficiency reasons. I am going to guess what is happening here is similar; and the "reused" items are not firing the `Loaded` event, because they were never re-loaded.

**So how do I get around it, and force the ComboBoxes to update each time the collection is changed, like how it does when the page first loads?**

**UPDATE**

The unexpected output from the print statement does not appear to be random - it appears to be consistently the last item in the `ListView`. So whenever the `SetItem()` function is called (after the initial time when the page loads), ONLY the `ComboBox` for the last item in the `ListView` fires its `Loaded` event. The `ComboBox` on the other items are scrambled, however... almost like they were all shifted up by one (and so have the `Status` of the next item in the `ListView` rather than the item they are on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Loaded` for this.

Let me show you a simple example:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="ListViewWithComboBoxExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:ListViewWithComboBoxExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="using:ListViewWithComboBoxExample.Models"
    x:Name="RootPage"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Click="AddRandomItemsButton_Click"
            Content="Add random item" />
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyDataType">
                    <!--
                        Using 'Binding' with 'ElementName' and 'Path' is the trick here
                        to access code-behind properties from the DataTemplate.
                    -->
                    <ComboBox
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=RootPage, Path=MyComboBoxOptions}"
                        SelectedValue="{x:Bind Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Tag="{x:Bind ID, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using ListViewWithComboBoxExample.Models;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ListViewWithComboBoxExample;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyComboBoxOptions { get; set; } = new()
    {
        "Active",
        "Inactive",
        "Unknown",
    };

    // ObservableCollections notify the UI when their contents change,
    // not when the collection itself changes.
    // You need to instantiate this here or in the constructor.
    // Otherwise, the binding will fail.
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataType> MyCollection { get; } = new();

    private void SetItem(MyDataType item)
    {
        MyCollection.Add(item);
    }

    private void AddRandomItemsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyCollection.Clear();

        Random random = new();
        int itemsCount = random.Next(100);

        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
        {
            MyDataType newItem = new()
            {
                ID = random.Next(100).ToString(),
                Status = MyComboBoxOptions[random.Next(MyComboBoxOptions.Count)],
            };

            SetItem(newItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, adapted to my code. It results in a null reference error from something that should never be null. The stack trace simply ends with [external code]. I am guessing the TwoWay binding mode is somehow trying to write a null value to something that otherwise is never null? For reference, MyDataType implements INotifyPropertyChanged, as does the Status (which is also a class). Would updating my question help?

Comment: If I toss in a null check where it throws the null reference error (and simply return), then the code runs, but the binding just doesn't work at all. I have verified that MyDataType and the Status property on MyDataType are never null nor set to null in my code.

Comment: I asked a separate question about the issue I am having with implementing this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76766943/how-to-twoway-data-bind-nested-inotifypropertychanged-viewmodels-to-combobox-ins.

Comment: Answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the SelectionChanged event handler rather than loaded. If I’m not mistaken, you can use them both, but it isn’t necessary. You can use a line of code in you method for your page (it’s the one that has “this.Initialize();”) that will load whatever it is you want on startup.

I’m not 100% sure what your program does. Try adding the other event handler; there are a few that could apply.